# How to fetch documents , in the order as their document ids are stored in some variable list/array , in cloud firestore firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

**I have an array or list of name "A", in which there are document Ids. Now I want to bring documents from cloud firestore, in the order in which their document Ids are stored in the list "A".**

"whereIn:" Only fetches documents in the order they are in collection of cloud firestore, but i want  to fetch in order as mentioned in the list.

Also, I am using ".getDocuments()", in order to fetch data,So please mention, if there any other efficient way of fetching data,which supports offline,caching.As, there can be some 200 to 400 documents.

**Code:**

```
    List A;//Not empty :), contains ordered document ids of the collection

   QuerySnapshot snapshot = await someCollectionRef.where('/*somefieldname*/', whereIn: A).getDocuments();

    List<Users> users = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => User.fromDocument(doc)).toList();//Here converting that snapshot data into list
```

**please mention, if there is any other efficient way of fetching data as I am here using ".getDocuments()",which supports offline,caching.As, there may be some 200 to 400 documents.**

*Thanks for the help in advance :)*

Comment: The order in which the documents are fetched doesn't seem to make a big difference.  You can just display them in the order you want after you fetch them.  You already have the order in list A.

Comment: @DougStevenson, that's the thing, i really have no idea how to do display them in that order of the list, so t i have thought that it's better to bring them in the order present in the list, rather than sorting them...

Comment: @DougStevenson, please help me out here sir.

Comment: It's not that hard to sort small amounts of data in client code.  If you're having problems with that, consider asking a new question with the code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson, i don't have small data, i have almost 300 documents.Sir, i have sorted the data,i.e document Id's, but I feel hard to fetch that those documents in that order. :{

Comment: 300 documents isn't very large.  That will sort in a few milliseconds on pretty much any modern device.  Definitely faster than it will take to transfer all those documents.

Comment: @DougStevenson, is it better to use pagination in my scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want, just change the element you want to compare in the data document:

```
querySnapshot.documents.sort((a, b) {
  return a.data['id'].compareTo(b.data['id']);
});
```

in the code above, i'm comparing the ID of these docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with your's above answer is , we are sorting the ids, by comparing them as which is greater than or smaller than, which doesn't fit in my scenario.

Comment: But, I have the id's sorted and stored in the list, Now need to bring them in that order,(or) bring them as the way they are stored in the firestore and display them as our order in the list, as  DougStevenson said.